# OpenTelemetry for messaging apps

Tags: open-telemetry, dynatrace

We have few micro services which picks messages from message bus, process it and again put the message on message bus.So there is no http call. We want to trace each message using open telemetry. Message bus is tightly coupled with message models and I don't have a way to inject trace id in the message. I'm new to open telemetry and have following questions

1. As I can not inject trace id while sending message to another service, can I use message id ( one of the property in message) to trace message from one app to other app ?
2. Is Context Propagation mandatory in this use case to co-relate parent and child span ? If yes how can I do this ?

Comment: The way this is done is usually through a separate "headers" concept that ESB frameworks provide. Trace/spanIDs go there as normal. The TraceID does not go as part of the "message contents".

Comment: What message bus are you using?

Comment: AMPS. See link https://devnull.crankuptheamps.com/documentation/html/develop/user-guide/html/chapters/queues.html#getting-started-with-amps-queues

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to the developers/company behind that specific queue technology and asking about distributed tracing/Open Telemetry. I don't see anything in the documentation at first glance but I did see a mention of "metadata", which would most likely be the mechanism to transport tracing information.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, AMPS supports a [message header called `CorrelationId`](https://www.crankuptheamps.com/blog/posts/2015/02/09/keeping-it-together-with-correlationid/).

This header could be used for context propagation. As far as I understand, it satisfies [context propagation requirements](https://github.com/open-telemetry/semantic-conventions/blob/main/specification/trace/semantic_conventions/messaging.md#context-propagation) that OpenTelemetry defines for messaging scenarios.